# Created Ubuntu Access Point, can't connect to it.

Tags: connection, wireless, lan

I have created a wireless access point on my eeepc 701 running a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.04. 
The configuration: 
Ubuntu 11.04 laptop --WIFI--> (ath0)eeepc (eth0) --ethernet cable-->My ISP router-->Internet

I followed this guide accurately: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router (only difference, I set my wireless card running Madwifi drivers issueing

```
sudo wlanconfig ath0 destroy, sudo wlanconfig ath0 create wlandev wifi0 wlanmode ap ath0
```

which seemed to work as my ath0 is now in Master mode.

My other machine can now see the connection, but can't seem to connect to it. Looks like the connection attempt times out.

Why could it be? I have spent two or three days reading how-tos and man pages, but as informative as it has been I still can't get things to work.

Some info (I put it on pastebin so I would not flood the thread, please tell me if I need to include it here):

http://pastebin.com/8pXrRB4p

Any help would be very appreciated. Please let me know if I need to post further info. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you do the dhcp stuff? Your 11.04 latop might be asking for an ip address but not getting on from your eeepc. Maybe set a static ip on the 11.04 laptop and see if that helps? Something like

```
address 192.168.0.2
network 192.168.0.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but setting a static IP on the 11.04 laptop did not change anything. I tried using the script posted here ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1488953 which did not help but at least it gives me an error I think I can work on:
    No subnet declaration for wlan0 (0.0.0.0). ** Ignoring  requests on wlan0. If this is not what you want, please write a subnet declaration in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment to which interface wlan0 is attached.

Comment: Was this error on the laptop or eeepc? If it was on the eeepc can you pastebin your /etc/dhcpd.conf . If it was on the laptop check that you set the subnet (netmask) to 255.255.255.0

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. That error is on my eeepc. My /etc/dhcpd.conf is empty, I put the configuration info into /etc/dhcpd3/dhcpd.conf, following an online tutorial. Here it is: pastebin.com/b8wGsa44 Should I set up the /etc/dhcp.conf instead? Thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/dhcp.html Looks like you need to edit /etc/default/dhcp3-server and tell it what interface to listen to (in your case ath0). Looking at the docs again it looks like /etc/dhcpd3/dhcpd.conf is the correct place now

Comment: I enabled ath0 in etc/default/dhcp3-server, with 
INTERFACES="ath0", but I get the same error, even after reboot. I have read the guide you linked but I can't find an answer to my problem. Any other ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Whats the output of ifconfig on the eeepc? It might be that the ip address of eth0 and the wireless are too similar. If eth0 is 192.168.x.x as well maybe change the dhcp settings to use 10.0.0.x or something similar. The 'ignoring requests on wlan0' is confusing me a bit.

Comment: Yeah sorry that was a typo, it says ignoring requests on ath0, but still quite confusing because every configuration file seems to be fine. I was also wondering if it could be that the IP addresses are too similar, I am going to try with something different and report back. Thanks a lot for your time, I appreciate it. –

Comment: Nope. I changed the IP to 10.0.0.1, but I get the same error. This is very frustrating, I don't understand. :(

Comment: (You are restarting dhcp on the eee after changing config files right?) Ok try plugging the laptop into the eee with a network cable (so unplug the router). If the laptop picks up an ip address from the eee then dhcp is working just on the wrong interface. Can you do pastebin an ifconfig on the ee just to make sure that is all ok. If dhcp still don't work then I would be tempted to set a static ip on both the eee and laptop you should be at least be able to ping each other, either over ethernet or wifi. If you can't over wifi then there is something wrong with the wifi settings.